# Get each element values separately from URL in jquery

Tags: jquery, decodeuricomponent

I have decoded uri:
 `min_price=0&max_price=628&category_id=71&page=1&path=71&old_route=product/category&review[]=3&attribute_value[20][]=new&attribute_value[1][]=Evaluate`

This URI can be each time different. Depend on checked component in a browser.

I need to get each separate  element and its value.
The main problem is to get each `review` and each `attribute_value`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: @freedomn-m thank you. I'll check again all. I have  tried to find solution  here, but no success.

Comment: It's not always easy - there's a few regarding search params, but most are to do with updating.  It's not clear how/if it works with your arrays.   Alternatively you could always `.split("&")` then sort